# Нужно ли обособлять в моём случае «прежде всего»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Эти слова невольно наводят нас на мысль о том, что человеку(,) **прежде всего**(,) необходимо иметь желание и стремление к учёбе, к той науке, которую он для себя выбрал.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь у *"прежде всего"* значение *"в первую очередь",* поэтому это не вводное слово и не обособляется. Подробнее [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_627).

*Необходимо человек**у**,* либо уж *человек **должен** иметь.* Желание к учёбе? Желание и стремление к науке? Так не пойдёт, надо перефразировать:

> Эти слова невольно наводят нас на мысль о том, что человеку прежде всего необходимо иметь стремление учиться, особенно той науке, которую он для себя выбрал.

Вместо *"особенно"* ещё лучше подошло бы *"прежде всего",* но для него уже "забронировано место", а повторяться не годится.

Comment: А если попробовать так: «Эти слова невольно наводят нас на мысль о том, что человеку прежде всего необходимо иметь желание учиться и стремиться постигнуть ту науку, которую он для себя выбрал.»

Comment: Лучше, но не очень. Можно прочитать как "иметь желание стремиться", что ерунда, вместо "необходимо стремиться". (Кстати, точку по-русски ставят после кавычек. (В британском английском так же.))

Comment: Зачем так многословно? Желание учиться и желание постигнуть науку - не одно и то же? Да и "постигнуть науку" - это века эдак из восемнадцатого. Высокий штиль! Вы к этому и стремитесь?

Comment: Насчёт точки поспешил) вы чересчур внимательны)

Comment: *вы чересчур внимательны* Ну уж простите, какой есть, решил на всякий случай сказать об этом — распространённая ошибка. Но я верю, что Вы знали, как правильно. :)

Answer (score 0):

ЧеловекУ. Запятые не нужны, здесь это не вводное слово.
Можно, конечно, при желании попытаться притянуть за уши "вводность", и это даже не будет грубой ошибкой. Я, мол, так вижу. Но всё-таки не нужно.

Фраза очень неряшливая. Желание к учёбе? Желание к науке?

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю